# same vendor code from multiple packages

Tags: go, grpc, godeps

I'm trying to use grpc `"google.golang.org/grpc"` package.

```
import (
    "github.com/xxxx/yyyy"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

conn, err := grpc.Dial(address)
pppp.NewXXXXClient(conn) // where pppp is from github.com/xxxx/yyyy
```

What happens if `github.com/xxxx/yyyy` also vendors the same grpc package?
I am getting a compilation error like below

```
cannot use conn (type *"google.golang.org/grpc".ClientConn) as type
*"github.com/xxxx/yyyy/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc".ClientConn
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Show the very line that triggers that compilation error.

Comment: @zerkms it is added now.

Comment: You can’t import the same packages from multiple paths. Move the vendored packages from your dependencies into the top level vendor directory.

Comment: Nested vendoring is a real pain to deal with and no solution is ideal.  Your easiest option is to manually delete the vendored package from xxxx/yyyy. If that fails because it is using a different version of grpc, vendor that version into your own project and leave it deleted from the external one.

Comment: @SteveHe: you should vendor that package so you do have control over it.

Comment: This is why it's generally considered bad practice to vendor dependencies in a library; vendoring should only be used for binaries.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you must vendor *every* dependency of your project (if necessary - include Go std library too), or you shouldn't use vendoring at all. There's no third choise.